# Why Intel TBB didn't provide conditional variable like boost?

Tags: multithreading, boost-thread, tbb

Like conditional signal mechanism, I want one task to wait until some signal is received or some variable becomes true.
Boost lib provide this mechanism, but TBB didn't.

How to implement this case in TBB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a very old TBB ?

Having tasks "wait" is something TBB hasn't handled well in the past, but the current TBB [news](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/whatsnew.php) contains this:

> ISO C++ thread class – A thin portable
>   wrapper around OS threads. It's a
>   close approximation of the ISO C++
>   200x class thread (Section 30.2 of
>   http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2691.pdf).
>   Now TBB lets you choose which is best,
>   task-based versus thread-based, for
>   your situation. Threads are typically
>   better than tasks when the "work" is
>   really more waiting than computation,
>   such as for:
>
> ```
> * GUI, I/O or network interface threads.
> * Threads that need to wait on external events.
> * Programs that previously needed to use both native threads and Intel® TBB tasks.
> ```

ie they're admitting TBB's task parallelism isn't a universal panacea and you need something more like the "traditional" threading model sometimes for I/O.  And indeed if you check the latest [reference manual](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/uploads/81/91/Latest%20Open%20Source%20Documentation/Reference.pdf) you'll find TBB does now contain condition variables!  (See section 8.4)